# Angular2+ how to get proper element order from QueryList<>

Tags: angular

so I have a sortable list which are several elements in an `*ngFor`, which I drag and drop.
On drop I would like to get the new order of the items.
So I added an event but the order of QueryList remains the same.

Here are some things I have tried with no luck

```
public getOrder() {

        var records: QueryList<SimpleGridRecord> = this.simpleGridRecords.length > 0 || this.simpleGridDraggable.simpleGridRecords;
        records.notifyOnChanges()
        // this.cd.detectChanges();
        records.forEach((s:SimpleGridRecord) => {
            console.log(s.index);
            console.log(s.item.getKey('id'));
        });

    }
```

is there anyway to get the updated order list of elements?

I keep index and id in my objects which I loop over

[image]

regards

Sean

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@ContentChildren()` or `@ViewChildren()` and subscribe to changes:

```
@ViewChildren(SimpleGridRecord) records: QueryList<SimpleGridRecord>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.records.changessubscribe(val => console.log(this.records.toArray()));
}
```

Comment: tx for the answer, that's exactly what I do, but the order of items is not the same order as it is in the HTML <li>

Comment: I added an image and as you can see, after a drop, X is first in the Query but Y is first in the UI :(

Comment: Do you update the order by direct DOM manipulation, or by changing the order of the array you use in `*ngFor`?

Comment: yes I update the order by direct DOM manipulation as I do a drag and drop to change the order of the items, which I have to touch the DOM

Comment: I thunk you should afterwards change the order in the array to let `*ngFor` redraw in the new order, them also the query will match.